# Semantics of pointer dereference operator `->`

Tags: c++

I am looking for some help regarding the  pointer dereference operator **`->`** . Let me describe what I am trying to do.

I am implementing a unidirectional iterator for a special container. The container is special in the sense that it does not physically allocate any space for the contained values but generates them at run time on demand. For example, consider that the container is "**M consecutive integral multiples of N**".

Since I do not want to store the value directly in my iterator, I create a value on the heap on demand.

When I need a pointer to the value I delete the old one if it's out-of-date and create a new one.  This means that invocation of **`operator *()`** or **`operator ->()`** may `delete` an old value and `new` a new value, if the iterator has been advanced with `operator ++()` after they were last invoked.

Now I would like to use a **`smart_ptr`** to point at my value rather than keep a native pointer around. In order to do so I realize I need to understand the semantics of the **`->`** operator better.

- First of all, is **`->`** a **unary** operator ?
- If that be so, how does **`i->member`** work. This would translate to `(pointer returned)member`, which is not a syntactically  valid form.
- **"member"** could be a data member or a member function.
- **`->()`** smells more like a binary operator that executes `(*pointer returned).member`. Since "member" is not a value, such a semantics is not equivalent to a binary operator either.
- What happens to the pointer returned by `->()` ? who is supposed to own it ?
- How can I use RAAI in this framework ? Is reference counted pointers the only option ?
- There is no `--` operator for this iterator so i don't need to keep the previous values around

Thanks for your responses. Ending with a meta question, should this be a wiki ?

Comment: `->()` is not an operator, so you might want to edit your question for more meaningful replies. `->` is an operator. `()` is an operator. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer to answer your questions, though I do not think they are so useful as you might hope:

- Yes, it is a unary operator
- No, it does not care what `member` is.  If `member` isn't a field/member of the class/struct pointed to be the return of `operator ->` then the compiler will complain.
- `member` could indeed be either a data member or a member function.
- No, it's a unary operator since it does nothing whatsoever with `member`.  It's there just to implement smart pointers.  It is perfectly valid to say `return_type *ptr = smarptr.operator ->()`.
- It's owned by whatever returns it.  But this is purely by convention.  You can decide whatever you want.  But if you decide anything other than that it will surprise a whole ton of people to the point they will think they have a bug in their program and will never think to wonder if your smart pointer implementation has some bizarre semantics nobody else uses.
- If you use `operator ->` for anything at all other than implementing a smart pointer I have no intentions of helping you write code that programmers after you will revile and make fun of.
- This is a statement, not a question, so I have no answer for it.  :-)

I question your desire to point at your value.  It seems to me like you could hold it by value as a member value of your iterator, and I will give an example of how this could work below.  But if you're set on using a pointer to your value, and want to use a smart pointer, just return the result of `smartptr.operator ->()` for your own `operator ->()`.  You might also use the member function of your smart pointer (often `get`) that returns a 'bare' pointer and that would likely confuse people a little less.

Here is a sample of how your example container should work:

```
class multiples {
  public:
   multiples(int n, int starting_multiplier, int ending_multiplier)
      : n_(n), starting_(starting_multiplier), ending_(ending_multiplier)
   {
   }

   class const_iterator {
      friend class multiples;
     public:
      const int &operator *() const { return curval_; }
      const int *operator ->() const { return &curval_; }

      const const_iterator &operator ++() { curval_ += n_; return *this; }
      const const_iterator operator ++(int) {
         const_iterator tmp(*this);
         curval += n_;
         return tmp;
      }

      bool operator ==(const const_iterator &b) const { return curval_ == b.curval_; }
      bool operator !=(const const_iterator &b) const { return curval_ != b.curval_; }

     protected:
      explicit const_iterator(int n, int starting) : n_(n), curval_(starting * n) {}

     private:
      const int n_;
      int curval_;
   };

   const_iterator begin() const { return const_iterator(n_, starting_); }
   const_iterator end() const { return const_iterator(n_, ending_); }

  private:
   const int n_, starting_, ending_;
};
```

Comment: I *am* defining  a `forward_iterator` but for a container that generates values on demand. I do not want any bizarre semantics, just understand the default semantics of `->` and how it functions, or _should_ function for such containers.

Comment: If that's your question, then that's easy.  You should squirrel away a value that contains the current value of your iterator.  `operator *` should return a const reference to that value, and `operator ->` should return a const pointer to it.

Comment: @srean - I'm sorry, but your question seemed really confused, and it really sounded like you were trying to make `operator ->` auto-increment your iterator or something really strange like that.  If you would like, I will edit my answer to tone it down, or leave it as is.  If I edited your question to be clearer, I think the answer would fall out so naturally that it would no longer be clear what the question was.  `operator ->` is one of those things that seems confusing until you see and then it's "Oh, that was so simple!".

Comment: For completeness I guess I need to implement `==` and `!=` as well. I want it to be a valid `forward_iterator` that I can pass to the usual STL algorithms.

Comment: @srean - Now edited to be less preachy.  :-)  Also, all operators are special forms.  It's just that the most overloaded ones are standard binary arithmetic operators or binary boolean operators and those are all very similar to one another in how they interact with the compiler.

Comment: @Omnifarous `->` seems exceptional. The result of other operator overloads are syntactically valid C++. But if one replaces the `->`call by its return value, the end result is not something that the compiler would have accepted otherwise. That is what threw me off. I think the consistency of scheme has spoiled me :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need to "create a value on the heap". At least for numbers, just let the iterator contain the iteration state directly.

Answer (score 0):

Much of it is answered by others. I'd still like to share how -> operator overloading works.

When we do `pA->Function()`, something like this happens behind the scenes `(pA.operator->())->Function()`

In RAII framework, the pointer class needs to behave as if it were an actual pointer. So one needs to overload the arrow `->` operator.

e.g. of an overloaded -> operator in RAII.

`T* operator->()

{

   return m_ptr;

}`

Comment: True, that much I understand. My (possibly unreasonable)expectation was that since its an operator I should be able to implement its standard behavior in C++. Its there that I fail, hence my question.